# How to include a .js file in another .js file when working with QML and QtQuick2? No browser involved

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

In order to include one `.js` file in another `.js` file I tried writing the following in a `.js` file.

```
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= 'helper.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

I got the error: `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Then I wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $(documuent).ready(function () { var editChange = $('td').replaceWith('<td id = "@Html.ValueFor(x => x.name)" >'); });
</script>
```

on the top of it, but got the error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Problem is that here no browser is involved. This `.js` file is working along `QML` and getting compiled with `qmake`.

What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the documentation on ["Importing JavaScript Resources in QML"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html) with the specific case of [importing in another JS file](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html#importing-a-javascript-resource-from-another-javascript-resource)

If you have a file `helper.js` and you want to use its functions in another javascript file you can do like that:

```
.import "helper.js" as Helper
```

Then you can use one of its functions like this:

```
Helper.myFunction();
```